# Function of spectra and cofinal subspectra

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectra

Let $E$ and $F$ be CW-spectra and $\tilde{F}$ be cofinal. Let $f \colon E \to F$ be a function of spectra. I am trying to prove: There is $\tilde{E} \subseteq E$ cofinal such that $f$ maps $\tilde{E}$ into $\tilde{F}$. See in Adams Blue Book III Lemma 2.6.(i).

My idea so far is to define a subspectrum $\tilde{E}$ such that $\tilde{E}_n$ is the disjoint union of the cells $e$ of $E_n$ with $f_n(e) \subseteq \tilde{F}$. At first, $\tilde{E}_n$ has to be a subspace of $E_n$, but this should be clear since $E_n$ is the disjoint union of its cells. But how do you show that this is a spectra, that means that the map $\Sigma E_n \to E_{n+1}$ maps $\Sigma \tilde{E}_n $ to $\tilde{E}_{n+1}$, and is my idea right so far?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\sigma_n: \Sigma E_n \to E_{n+1}$ restricts to $\Sigma \tilde{E}_n \to \tilde{E}_{n+1}$ we must show that $f_{n+1}$ maps $\sigma_n(\Sigma\tilde{E}_n)$ into $\tilde{F}_{n+1}$ (because then by definition $\sigma_n(\Sigma\tilde{E}_n) \subset \tilde{E}_{n+1}$). That is, we must show that $f_{n+1}(\sigma_n(\Sigma\tilde{E}_n)) \subset \tilde{F}_{n+1}$.

Since $f$ is a function of spectra, $f_{n+1}(\sigma_n(\Sigma \tilde{E}_n)) = \tau_n(\Sigma f_n(\Sigma\tilde{E}_n))$ (here $\tau_n$ is a structure map of $F$). The latter is indeed a subset of $\tilde{F}_{n+1}$, since $f_n$ maps $\tilde{E}_n$ into $\tilde{F}_n$, so  $\Sigma f_n$ maps $\Sigma \tilde{E}_n$ into $\Sigma \tilde{F}_n$, and so since $\tilde{F}$ is a subspectrum $\tau_n$ maps $\Sigma \tilde{F}_n$ into $\tilde{F}_{n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you, but how does from $f_{n+1}(\sigma_n (\Sigma \tilde{E}_m)) \subset \tilde{F}_{n+1}$ follows the claim? If $x \in \sigma_n (\Sigma \tilde{E}_m)$ then it is $f_{n}(x) \in \tilde{F}_{n+1}$, but $x$ could be still contained in a cell with $f_n(e) \not\subset \tilde{F}_{n+1}$.

Comment: I should've made it clear what this argument shows - it shows that $\sigma_n$ restricted to $\Sigma \tilde{E}_n$ has image contained in $\tilde{E}_{n+1}$. This is necessary for $\tilde{E}$ to be a spectrum. This is one step - other steps are to show that $f$ maps $\tilde{E}$ into $\tilde{F}$ (follows easily from the definition) and that $\tilde{E}$ is cofinal (follows from cofinality of $\tilde{F}$  and the fact that $f$ is a function of spectra). If you still have doubts, let me know.

Comment: I still dont know how the statement that $\tilde{E}$ is a spectrum follows from this. Like I said: an element of $\sigma_n(Sigma \tilde{E}_n)$ should be in $\tilde{E}_{n+1}$, but I dont see why its cell should be mapped to $\tilde{F}_{n+1}$.

Comment: @Candyblock right, I see what you mean now, valid point. I think we can fix this by assuming all maps are cellular (either to begin with or using cellular approximation) and then carrying out a similar argument to the one I gave, but not starting with points $x \in \Sigma E_n$ but rather cells $e \subset \Sigma E_n$.